# String selection in R shows invisible characters when selecting column by index (and not by name)

Tags: r, string, csv, date

I have an issue in R where I want to transform date data.
I first pull data from a csv (using read.csv2 and fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM" parameter to prevent random naming of columns).
The dates in my csv *(ouvrages)* column *(date_mes)* are in dd/mm/yyyy format, and I want to set it in yyyy-mm-dd format to ease the use within R code.
Therefore I use this line of code to do so :
ouvrages <- ouvrages_brut %>% mutate(date_mes_norme = as.Date(paste0(substr(ouvrages_brut$date_mes, start = 7, stop = 10),"-",substr(ouvrages_brut$date_mes, start = 4, stop = 5) ,"-", substr(ouvrages_brut$date_mes, start = 1, stop = 2))))
I get what I want from this line of code.

But the problem I get comes when I want to set this to a function to reuse it more conveniently elsewhere in my project, specifically when I call the column by index and not by name.
My working code show this :

`substr(ouvrages_brut$date_mes, start = 1, stop = 10)`
`[1] "01/01/1959" "01/01/1965" "01/01/1972" "01/01/1979" "01/01/1980" "01/01/1983" "01/06/2017" "01/10/2023" [9] "01/11/2023" "01/01/2024" "31/03/2024" "30/06/2024" "30/06/2027" "30/06/2028" "30/06/2029" "30/12/2035" [17] "01/12/2036"...`

While substr(ouvrages_brut[,2], start = 1, stop = 10) shows this :

`substr(ouvrages_brut[,2], start = 1, stop = 10)`
`[1] "c(\"01/01/1"`

No matter how I turn this, I get these unwanted c("" characters everywhere.

I suspect this problem comes from encoding, but I have no clue how to solve this.

I've tried using alternative functions such as substring but it didn't change anything.
Also I didn't find so far anyone having my problem on the website.

Thank you for your help and attention

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the indexes. Try `substr(ouvrages_brut[,2], start = 1, stop = 10)`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, 
Sadly, no I made a copy mistake here but in fact I had tried [,2], it actually gives me the same result. However, you are right since it should be [,2] (and this accidentally works because it's the second value in the tibble).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.